# What is the alternative way to return in the middle of loop in the Elixir world

Tags: elixir

I am still new to Elixir. I am trying to create a method that takes a list of requests and process each request. Return {:ok, "success"} if all passed or {:error, error_reason} if one failed.

In other languages, I can do something like this. Assume the process function return either {:ok, "success"} or {:error, error_reason}.

```rb
def func(requests):
   for request in requests:
       if {:error, error_reason} <- process(request):
           return {:error, error_reason}

   return {:ok, "success"}
end
```

What is the proper way to do this in the Elixir world?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use recursion:

```rb
def func([head | tail]) do
  case process(head) do
    {:error, reason} -> {:error, reason}
    {:ok, _} -> func(tail)
  end
end

def func([]), do: {:ok, "success"}
```

Loops are inherently imperative and Elixir is at heart a functional language, so recursion and higher-order functions are the more natural alternative to using loops I think.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I somehow glossed over that part. Then `Enum.find` is definitely not appropriate. I would always choose a higher-order function if available, but as I don't think there is one readily available that applies to this scenario I would implement it using recursion instead. I've edited my answer with a slight modification to the earlier recursive suggestion that I hope better fits what you're asking for.

Comment: `Enum.find/2` actually works. I played with that function a bit, like
`funs = (1..100) |> Enum.map(&(fn-> IO.inspect(&1) end))` then `Enum.find(funs, &(&1.() == 5))`, it only prints 5 numbers, not 100 numbers.

Comment: Interesting @Aetherus, I can indeed reproduce your result as well, but that seems to contradict the documentation: _"Finally, note the functions in the Enum module are eager: they will traverse the enumerable as soon as they are invoked. This is particularly dangerous when working with infinite enumerables. In such cases, you should use the Stream module, which allows you to lazily express computations, without traversing collections, and work with possibly infinite collections."_ So I'm not sure how safe it would be to rely on this.

Comment: The [`Stream` documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Stream.html) also elaborates on this being the defining difference. And unfortunately there is no `Stream.find` or equivalent functions either.

Comment: The laziness of `Stream` functions is irrelevant in this case. `Stream` functions run in such way that when asked by the "downstream", it pulls just one item from the "upstream", process it, and pass it to the downstream. `Stream` functions can only perform **local** operations (which needs only the current item). On the other hand, the `Enum` functions just use as many items as needed to reach the conclusion, and returns the whole conclusion, so `Enum` functions can perform non-local operations like `reduce` and `group_by` and `find`.